# SQLGrammarException: could not execute query: Column not found?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have the following `hibernate` query string:

```
 String queryString = "select \r\n" +
                    "cms.my_status_id as 'myStatusId',\r\n" +
                    "cms.status_label as 'statusLabel',\r\n" +
                    "csl.status_id as 'companyStatusLabel'\r\n" +
                    "from "+client+".corresponding_status cms \r\n" +
                    "join "+client+".company_status_label csl on csl.status_id = cms.my_status_id";
```

My Corresponding Entity is:

```
@Entity(name = "corresponding_status")
@Table(name = "corresponding_status")
public class CorrespondingStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "my_status_id")
    private Integer myStatusId;

    // varchar(255)
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "status_label")
    private String statusLabel;

    @JsonProperty
    @Transient
    private String companyStatusLabel;
```

However when I run the query I get:

```
Column 'my_status_id' not found
```

even though it is definitely in the DB.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Can you show us the final query.

Comment: @jarlh how do I do so? thanks

Comment: Paste your logging output in the question

Comment: The `\r\n` are completely unnecessary and might be causing issues

Comment: Your `CorrespondingStatus` entity does not appear to have relationships to any other entities.  Why are you trying to do a join here?

Comment: @Turing85 what should I do instead then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HQL you must use properties instead of database column names. Change your HQL to

```
String queryString = "select \r\n" +
                "cms.myStatusId as 'myStatusId',\r\n" +
                "cms.statusLabel as 'statusLabel',\r\n" +
                "csl.status_id as 'companyStatusLabel'\r\n" +
                "from "+client+".corresponding_status cms \r\n" +
                "join "+client+".company_status_label csl with csl.status_id = cms.myStatusId";
```

EDIT:
You probably need to change company_status_label entity accordingly

EDIT2: Changed to WITH

Comment: HQL joins don't have an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building JPA queries by hand, I would suggest the [criteria API](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries). Your query above would change from:

```
String queryString = "select \r\n" +
                    "cms.my_status_id as 'myStatusId',\r\n" +
                    "cms.status_label as 'statusLabel',\r\n" +
                    "csl.status_id as 'companyStatusLabel'\r\n" +
                    "from "+client+".corresponding_status cms \r\n" +
                   "join "+client+".company_status_label csl on csl.status_id = cms.my_status_id";
```

to something akin to:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entity> cq = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> root = cq.from(Entity.class);
cq.select(root);
Query<Entity> query = session.createQuery(cq);
List<Entity> results = query.getResultList();
```